# Error in finding user who opened an excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a piece of code that checks if an excel file opened or not by someone and display that user's username if it is opened. It was working fine, but recently it is throwing some error as shown in picture. But the error occurs only sometimes and not always. Anyone knows why?

```
Sub TestFileOpened()

Dim Folder As String
Dim FName As String
Dim fileOpenedOrNot As String

fileOpenedOrNot = "\\122.00.00.000\shared\Admin Confidential\Admin_Planner Database\Admin\Templates and Files\~$Running Numbers and ComboBox Lists.xlsx"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFSO.FileExists(fileOpenedOrNot) Then
    fileInUse = True
    MsgBox "Database is opened and using by " & GetFileOwner(fileOpenedOrNot) & ". Please wait a few seconds and try again", vbInformation, "Database in Use"
Else
    fileInUse = False
End If

End Sub

Function GetFileOwner(strFileName)
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:")
    Set objFileSecuritySettings = _
    objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" & strFileName & "'")
    intRetVal = objFileSecuritySettings.GetSecurityDescriptor(objSD)

    If intRetVal = 0 Then
       GetFileOwner = objSD.Owner.Name
    Else
       GetFileOwner = "Unknown"
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

The following is the line that throwing error
`objWMIService.Get("Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting='" & strFileName & "'")`

**Update 1**

After further checks, I noticed there were no temp file `~$Running Numbers and ComboBox Lists.xlsx` created although that file is opened. Basically `objFSO.FileExists(fileOpenedOrNot)` setting to `true` and going into that `if` condition. But when it calls the `GetFileOwner` function, it is not seeing the file and probably that is why have the error.

Like I mentioned, this code was working earlier without issues, but all of a sudden having such problem. Anyone knows why there is no such temp file created?

Comment: Please include which line throws the error in your question.

Comment: `fileOpenedOrNot = \\122.00.00.000\ … \~$Running Numbers and ComboBox Lists.xlsx"` is missing the opening quote right after the `= `.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: That was a typo when I copied it to stack overflow. I just corrected it. My actual code have opening quotes. So that is not the issue here. It is something else

Comment: 2 ideas if it occurs only sometimes: Either the file was recently closed (between checking its existance and getting the owners name) but that should rarely happen because it is not very likely to hit that exact timing often. Or the server `\\122.00.00.000` cannot be reached or answers to slow, maybe heavy traffic. Check if it also happens with a local file so you can exclude client/server issues to be the reason.

Comment: Also, check the value of `strFileName` when you get the error. Is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: As you said first is quite unlikely to happen. For the second point, there is no heavy traffic. Only 3 users using it sometimes

Comment: I did some checks, and I could get your code working for local files but not for files on a server using an UNC path. If I mount the UNC path as local drive, the code works, but still it dosn't give the correct user name instead, I got "Administrators" as result but the one who had the file open was another user. So it looks to me that the code does not work with UNC server paths and it does not resolve the username properly neither. • So my suggestion is to write a logfile at `Workbook_Open` that includes the username and kill it on `Workbook_BeforeClose` that would work and is reliable.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think it has some incompatibility issue with latest excel versions and not other suspects. Because this code was working fine in the old version of excel. But now this intermittent issue started only after upgraded to office 365

Comment: @Anu I am not using 365. I am using Office Professional Plus 2019. But your code is not only using VBA. It uses the *Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)* which is actually causing the issue (WMI is throwing the error you see in VBA). So it is very unlikely that VBA (or an office update) is the issue. More likely any Windows update could break it or anything that changed too and you did not consider yet.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ: Alright...is there any example that you can show how to do the logging? I checked online but able to find some logging codes for the `Activeworkbook` or `ThisWorkbook` only. For my case, I am using a macro file to check another workbook to see if it is opened by someone and if it is then get the username of that user

Comment: @Anu The file that you want to check needs the logging.

Comment: Is the workbook in discussion **a shared one**?

Comment: @FaneDuru: Nope. it is not shared workbook

Comment: I am afraid that your code could not return the information about the workbook being open. It considers it open if it only **exists** in the supplied path. Then, it does not return the user's name who are opening it. In the way the code looks, it should return the owner. The one who created the workbook... If you test the code on local, it will return like being open by a user, an workbook **not open** and the owner will also be returned like the user who created it... I do not think that "Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting" can simple read this information on the network, without a sp. service.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this method works for you. Looks like it works for me better than yours but still it throws me `Predefined\Administrators` as owner on the network instead of the correct user name.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Const fileOpenedOrNot As String = "\\122.00.00.000\shared\Admin Confidential\Admin_Planner Database\Admin\Templates and Files\~$Running Numbers and ComboBox Lists.xlsx"
    
    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If objFSO.FileExists(fileOpenedOrNot) Then
        Dim objFile As Object
        Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(fileOpenedOrNot)
        
        MsgBox GetFileOwner(objFile.ParentFolder & "\", objFile.Name)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetFileOwner(ByVal fileDir As String, ByVal fileName As String) As String
    Dim securityUtility As Object
    Set securityUtility = CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility")
    
    Dim securityDescriptor As Object
    Set securityDescriptor = securityUtility.GetSecurityDescriptor(fileDir & fileName, 1, 1)
    
    GetFileOwner = securityDescriptor.Owner
End Function
```

Comment: This is not showing any error. But it is not getting the username as you said in my case too